# What is the proper way of adding a custom field to Keystone (to be included in an admin UI form)?

Tags: keystonejs

I can see the nice explanation for fields, and what they are made of, here: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/v4.0.0-beta.5/fields

How do you go about adding a custom field?

Is adding a custom field (versioned in my own project which depends on keystone, or perhaps done generic enough that could be pushed to npm) a matter of importing it during the keystone setup script and somehow mutating the `keystone` instance or whatever in order that it also loads my field along with the built-in ones?

EDIT:

The use case is in the context of the admin UI (e.g. you have a User keystone model, and you want the User form to have a new custom field whose UI is an arbitrary react component you implement)

Comment: What kind of field are you needing? Could you provide more detail?

Comment: @jlafay Many. e.g. one that's like a drag 'n' drop area for uploading multiple images to a cloud service. Another that's like a multiple attr/value tuples, in which the selection of each one may depend on the previous one, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The framework does support storage fields like local file, s3, azure, cloudinary images and embedly fields. That might satisfy your file field needs.

**Custom Fields**

It appears that the keystone wiki has a short tutorial on the [keystonejs wiki](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/wiki/Create-a-custom-field-type-for-app-development) and at time of writing, custom types aren't supported in the admin UI.

The example code in the wiki includes a validation method for a credit card number, so this might be the type of functionality that you're looking for.

Here's a short example of what a custom type would look like. It's a field that only accepts Jeff or Alexander as a valid value. You would put it in its own myNameType.js file.

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var util = require('util');

/*
    Custom FieldType Constructor
    @extends Field
    @api public
*/
function myName(list, path, options) {
    // add your options to this
    // call super_  
    this._nativeType = Text;
    myName.super_.call(this, list, path, options);  
}

/* inherit Field */
util.inherits(myName, keystone.Field);    

/* override or add methods */
myName.prototype.validateInput = function(data) {
    console.log('validate my name');
    var isValid = false;

    if (data && (data.toLower() === 'jeff' || data.toLower() === 'alexander')) {
        isValid = true;
    }

    return isValid;
};
```

Then register your type in the keystonejs startup file:

```
// Require keystone
var keystone = require('keystone');

 // add a new custom Field Type
Object.defineProperty(
    keystone.Field.Types,
    'MyName',
    { 
        get: function() {
            // or whatever your path is
            return require('./myName.js');
        } 
    }
);
```

From there you can use it in a model (remember to set it to hidden because of the lack of admin UI support):

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Person = new keystone.List('Post', {
    map: { name: 'title' },
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true },
    sortable: 'unshift',
    perPage: 5,
    track: true,
    autocreate: true
});

Person.add({
    name: { type: Types.MyName, label: 'My Name', hidden: true },
    heightInInches: { type: Types.Number, label: 'Height (inches)' },
});

Person.register();
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd gathered that much from studying the built-in types. I should have clarified that I specifically need to extend the admin UI. I will edit. But yeah, it seems like extending the admin UI without hacks isn't possible. I just wanna add a custom field to an entity's form and have its UI be any arbitrary UI I want. BTW the new way of using S3 with the Storage field, doesn't handle uploading multiple images.